# NLog Configuration Section Handlers Not Available in Net Standard

Tags: c#, .net, nlog, .net-standard

I am currently using the NET Framework implementation of NLog, using the standard NLog Configuration Section Handler in my app.config. When I want to migrate the library to NET Standard, I looked at the source code, which has a line

```
#if !SILVERLIGHT && !__IOS__ && !__ANDROID__ && !NETSTANDARD".
```

Why is the `NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler` not supported in the NET Standard package? it doesn't seem like there should be an issue here. If it is not supported for a good reason, how should I go about the Section handler for the NET Standard conversion if I cannot use the default?

Answer (score 2):

This is fully intentional, since System.Configuration is not part of NetStandard. This is why there is an explicit nuget-package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/

[NLog 4.5](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog) reduced its dependencies to make it compatible for most NetCore-platforms. The coming NLog 5.0 will try to strip its dependencies even further.

NetCore-applications uses `appsettings.json` by default, instead of legacy `app.config`. It is possible to load the [NLog-config from appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/Json-NLog-Config) along with [config-settings](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/ConfigSetting-Layout-Renderer).

NLog still tries to load [NLog.config from all known locations](https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#file-locations), no matter if you are using NetCoreApp or .NET Framework application.

And ofcourse if you have a legacy .NET Framework application, then NLog will load from `app.config` as you are used to.